# sudo file in sudoers - why user can modify file?

Tags: security, sudo

I want to allow one user to run specialscript.sh as root

so in his folder i created

```
-rwxr----  1 root deployers     142 Jul 16 14:07 specialscript.sh
```

and in sudoers.d/specialscripts:

```
user123 ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /home/user123/specialscript.sh



$ sudo specialscript.sh
Running script as user root
$
```

perfect

other users can't access to `/home/user123` files - so it is secure. if some user moves it to other folder it won't work.

BUT

because user is in group deployers he can see the content of this file (and this is intentional).

BUT he can also edit this file.
After save the ownership changed to

```
-rwxr----  1 user123 user123    142 Jul 16 14:07 specialscript.sh
```

BUT he can still run it as root...

```
$ sudo specialscript.sh
Running script as user root
HAHAHA! I CAN RUN rm -rf!
$
```

for now the only prevention i can see is to change group or remove read (which prevents reading)
or `chattr +i /home/user123/specialscript.sh`

but this is not obvious behaviour...

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this. If I try to edit the file, it is unwritable, as it should be.

Comment: What are permissions of the parent directory, `/home/user123`?

Comment: i think there is a lot if missing information, please see [ask] imho, if you put test.sh in user1 and user2 has sudo rights, then he can run but not edit the file over sudo due the limiation, but if user1 will be used for login - there will no protection moreover, a chmod 711 would be enough in my mind - because excetion does not require read rights

Comment: If the user has write permissions to the parent directory, `/home/user123`, then he can remove and re-create the file with the same name.

Comment: Why not just avoid all of this and put the file in another directory with the same permissions for both the file and the directory. That way, `user123` doesn't own the file and can't delete it and create another file with the same name that doesn't else that isn't wanted?

Comment: permissions of parent directory are default, folder was created by adduser user123

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The owner of the parent directory cannot edit the file, but can remove & recreate it:

Removal:

```
$ ls -aslh
total 8,0K
4,0K drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4,0K 17. 7. 12:35 .
4,0K drwxr-xr-x 6 user user 4,0K 17. 7. 12:34 ..
   0 -rwxr-x--- 1 root adm     0 17. 7. 12:35 test.sh
$ rm test.sh 
rm: remove write-protected regular empty file 'test.sh'? y
```

Re-creation with a different user (inherited from the parent directory):

```
$ touch test.sh
$ chmod 750 test.sh 
$ ls -aslh
total 8,0K
4,0K drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4,0K 17. 7. 12:36 .
4,0K drwxr-xr-x 6 user user 4,0K 17. 7. 12:34 ..
   0 -rwxr-x--- 1 user user    0 17. 7. 12:36 test.sh
```

To prevent this, place the script in a path where all the parent directories are owned by `root:root`. By the [Linux directory structure](https://www.howtogeek.com/117435/htg-explains-the-linux-directory-structure-explained/) convention, such path would be `/usr/local/sbin/script.sh`.

> The `/usr/local` directory is where locally compiled applications install to by default — this prevents them from mucking up the rest of the system.

> The `/sbin` directory is similar to the `/bin` directory. It contains essential binaries that are generally intended to be run by the root user for system administration.